# Limit website access to registered devices

Tags: android, ios, content-management-system, subscriptions

I run a media based website and we're looking at paid subscriptions as an option to monetise the website. In order to make this work, we would need to limit the number of devices that could access the website per subscription to prevent users simply sharing their access.

I've seen these method used on Now TV by Sky, where you can register up to 4 devices to an account that may use the service.

An alternative would be to make sure that you can only login via one device at a time, so that if you try to access from a second location simultaneously it'll login out the first person.

Any suggestions on how to implement these methods would be very welcome.

Comment: Use a simple login based mechanism? Second approach would be to use AES Encryption - assign keys to users, if you want to overcome the burden of logging in users.

Comment: How about grab the device id when they register a device, and if they remove that device id and replace it with another, it means they are using another device. Trouble is device id can change just by reformatting the device, so to have a better user experience, cross compare it with the IMEI, if both have changed, then they have definitely changed devices, if the device id has changed and the IMEI has not, then they are probably on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can use the `PhoneId` as it's unique per device.

So for each account you will have at most 5 `AndroidID` linked to it.

To retrieve the `AndroidID`:

```
 private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

However this id can be changed after a hard reset or if the user have a rooted phone and the necessary knowledge.

Then in the login you just have to verify both the `AndroidId` and the credentials.